# Prevent Excessive Builds in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm running on TeamCity 6.0.4. I have two projects, Foo and Bar, each producing artifacts. Those artifacts are consumed by Repo, and then an artifact produced by Repo is consumed by Leaf.

My problem is that Bar depends on Foo. So when Foo builds, the following events happen:

1. Foo builds. This triggers both Bar and Repo.
2. Bar builds. This triggers Repo to build again.
3. Leaf sees two Repo builds, which means Leaf builds twice.

How should I fix this to prevent the unnecessary (and inappropriate) build of Leaf?

**Note:** Having Foo not trigger Repo may solve the problem temporarily, but when we introduce Baz (which also depends on Foo), then we have the problem again:

1. Foo builds. This triggers Bar and Baz.
2. Bar builds. This triggers Repo to build.
3. Baz builds. This triggers Repo to build.
4. Leaf sees two Repo builds, which means Leaf builds twice.

Baz is forthcoming.

Suggestions?

Comment: My thought was to have Repo absorb all the triggers in some time period and only produce one build out of them, but I don't anywhere that TeamCity permits that.

Comment: Also note that this is a series of projects that depend on artifacts of previous projects, so it doesn't seem like source snapshots will help me. If I'm wrong, I'd like to be educated!

Comment: My current best solution is to consolidate Foo, Bar, and Baz into a single build project. But this obscures error messaging when builds fail, prevents the firing Repo of all three when even one is breaking, and creates a very hefty project where it's unclear what aspects relate to which.